# Qgis Google Base Hybrid Image Updation Notification

Tags: google-maps, notifications, qgis, google-earth

We are using Qgis for capture features, and the base map is google rendering hybrid image. And the base map is connected via google server link in Qgis. whenever google updates their base images, horizontal shifts are occurred between the existing and updated images.so quality of the captured features were affected (i.e) Horizontal shifts are occurred.If there is any chance to get the notifications regularly while google updates their basemap.Please share with us

Comment: Please elaborate your question and share us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

We are using Qgis for capture features, and the base map is google rendering hybrid image. And the base map is connected via google server link in Qgis. whenever google updates their base images, horizontal shifts are occurred between the existing and updated images.so quality of the captured features were affected (i.e) Horizontal shifts are occurred.If there is any chance to get the notifications regularly while google updates their basemap.Please share with us